# Are my variables/samples dependent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have a data set of student written productions. I extracted textual features from all of them, e.g. number of words, number of verbs, sentence length etc. I am trying to prove that productions written at different school grades can be discriminated by these features.

I have a dataframe like so:

```
Student.........Words...........Verbs........Mean Sentence length.......Grade

Student 1...... 450..............80...................12.................10 

Student 2......100...............20...................8..................5

Student 3.......35...............50...................10.................3

Student .4.....600................150.................15.................10

Student 5......90................30...................7..................5

Student 6......30................5....................5..................3

Student 7......550...............100..................13.................10

Student 8......120...............35...................7...................5

Student 9......4.................10...................5...................3
```

...

I wanted to test whether there were *significant differences in the means of each feature per group*, but the more I read the more confused I get.

It seems like I cannot perform ANOVA for each feature because my data is not normally distributed. So I performed Kruskal-Wallis by pairing each feature with the grade, but I just found that you should not do that if your samples are dependent...

So, would you say my samples are dependent? Which statistical test would you perform?

Comment: What seems dependent to you?

Comment: @Dave One might say, the number of verbs depends on the number of words? (I have no idea what I am saying)

Comment: Sure, there should be a relationship between number of words and number of verbs. What does that have to do with your test?

Comment: which are the 'groups'? Schools, gender, etc.? "I am trying to prove that productions written at different school grades can be discriminated by these features." What are the "productions" exactly?

Comment: The groups are the grades, in the example, grades 3, 5 and 10. The productions are essays written by the students. I wanna show that the features extracted from the essays can discriminate the different grades.

Comment: @Dave I want to do if I can srill perform Kruskal-Wallis in this type of data to show that the groups can indeed be discriminated by the features.

Comment: What do you think is the outcome that is the most theoretically useful? You have three potential outcomes here that are all related to each other. If you are set on ANOVA, I would determine which of the three is most important and then go from there. For example, why would sentences differ between grades? Are some grades being taught sentence dictation at older levels? Or children who are too young unlikely to write a full sentence? It would be good to have an analysis with a plausible theory backing it up.